# rails ajax request returning not found but controller function exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some problems with an Ajax function. I got an error `500` from the server.

The Ajax function looks like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= url_for(:controller => "movies", :action => "test") %>",
    data: {inputtag: tag }
  })
```

In my movies controller, I have this function

```
 # Fügt dem Video einen Tag hinzu
 def test
   @tag = Tag.new
   if request.post?
      @tag.update_attributes(params[:inputtag])
      if @tag.save
        redirect_to :back
      else
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
```

So, I do not know Why I got this error:

```
http://lvh.me/movies/test 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual Ruby error that you're getting?

Comment: Url exits that's why u r facing 500 error, now paste the exact error which u r facing

Comment: Shouldn't the string insertion `<%=` end with `%>`, not `=>`?

Comment: whats the route for movies controller? and provide more details of error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the entry in your routes.rb file

```
resources :movies do
  collection do
    get 'test'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

500 status is not about routing. Check your controller action, specifically this.

> @tag.update_attributes(params[:inputtag])

You are trying to update a record that does not exist and you are not using the strong parameters of Rails properly. So try this instead.

```
  def test
    @tag = Tag.create tag_params
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  # If your tag model looks like: Tag(id: integer, inputtag: string)
  def tag_params
    params.require(:tag).permit(:inputtag)
  end
```